# Скрываем форму после отправки

Tags: php

Наткнулся на непонятный скрипт. Вот пример как скрывается форма после отправки:

```
    <?php
    //Если город пустой - покажем форму
    if (isset($_REQUEST['city'])) {
?>
        <form action="" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
<?php
    }
?>

<?php
    //Если форма была отправлена и город не пустой:
    if (isset($_REQUEST['city'])) {
        $city = strip_tags($_REQUEST['age']);
        echo 'Ваш город: '.$age;
    }
?>
```

И это работает) Везде разные значения : `$_REQUEST['city'] , name="name", $_REQUEST['age']` ПОЧЕМУ?????

И это мой код)) Конечно же ничего не скрывает)

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_REQUEST['city'])){
?> 
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="city">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
     }
?> 

<?php

if (empty($_REQUEST['city'])){
    $city = strip_tags($_REQUEST['city']);
    echo "Ваш город: $city";
}else{
    echo "Чувак, ты забыл ввести город!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Неправильное условие:

```
   if ( ! empty($_REQUEST['city'])){
        $city = strip_tags($_REQUEST['city']);
        echo "Ваш город: $city";
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

```
//Если город пустой - покажем форму
if (isset($_REQUEST['city'])) {
```

Не правильно. Функция isset() определяет, установлена (существует) ли переменная но не проверяет значение в ней

Если переписывать, тогда так

```
<? 
if(!isset($_GET['city'])){
?> 
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="city">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?
}elseif(!empty($_GET['city'])){
    echo "Ваш город: ".strip_tags($_GET['city']); 
}else{
    echo "Чувак, ты забыл ввести город!";
}
?>
```